# How to recognize the assignment operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've got class with overloaded `[]` and I need to make it to recognize, when I try to set the values to the array. I assume, that I'll have to overload the operator `=`, nevertheless I don't know, how shall that whole stuff look like. Part of my code:

```
class Matrix {
public:

Matrix(int x, int y);
~Matrix(void);
Matrix& operator =(const Matrix &matrix); //ok...this is probably wrong...

class Proxy {
public:

    Proxy(double* _array) : _array(_array) {
    }

    double &operator[](int index) const {
        return _array[index];
    }

private:
    double* _array;
};

Proxy operator[](int index) const {
    return Proxy(_arrayofarrays[index]);
}

Proxy operator[](int index) {
    return Proxy(_arrayofarrays[index]);
}

int x, y;
double** _arrayofarrays;
};
```

So I just need to be able to recognize when I try to set `Matrix matrix(3,3); matrix[0][0]=1;`
Everything else works allright, so I assumed that it's not needed to paste the whole code

Comment: What's wrong with it? What do you mean "need to be able to recognize"?

Comment: `double` is the the assignment operator is changing. You shouldn't need to provide one.

Comment: [Why you shouldn't do that](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/matrix-subscript-op.html) ([part 2](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/matrix-array-of-array.html)).

Comment: I want to throw my own Exception, when the user want's to access wrong indexes, so I need to assume, I need be able to notice, that the user is trying to set the value and check the indexes first.

Comment: @n.m. Heh..trust me, that it wasn't my idea...I just have to implement it as a homework and I've got some specifics and I can't do it other way, ie `[][]` indexes...

Comment: 1) Please don't use raw pointers for arrays, if you can avoid them. 2) Please don't return a `double&` from a `operator[] (..) const`. 3) Boundary checks should be done in the accessors (`operator[]`  or `operator()`)

Comment: `Proxy(double* _array) : _array(_array)` is terrible style.

Comment: Search the web for "C++ FAQ Matrix", it will give you better options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want something which is not directly possible:  `operator[][].`

You can emulate the behavior of this by using an intermediate class:
Since a Matrix class is typically indexed as [rows][columns], you can
have the first operator method return the corresponding Row object.
The row class can than overload the operator[] and return the corresponding
element.

```
Row& Matrix::operator[](int r);  
double& Row::operator[](int c);
```

Now when you create your matrix object, you can index it as expected:

```
Matrix matrix(3,3);  
matrix[0][0] = 1;
```

The last line is then equivalent to calling:

```
matrix.operator[](0).operator[](0) = 1;
```

To check for out-of-bounds indices, store the matrix sizes:

```
Proxy operator[](int index) {
    assert(index < num_rows);
    return Proxy(_arrayofarrays[index]);
}

double &operator[](int index) const {
    assert(index < num_cols);
    return _array[index];
}
```

As Aldo suggeested, Proxy can be passed the array length value in it's constructor:

```
 Proxy(double* _array, int _length) : _array(_array), num_cols(_length){
 }
```

As a general rule of thumb, if you're passing a raw array to a function, you will almost always want to pass the length of that array as well.

Comment: my operator `[][]` work pretty well... I can create new instance of the class ie `Matrix matrix(5,5);` then add or read elements there...I just don't know, how to catch,when user tries to access out of bounds index :[

Comment: I see what you mean now. Your proxy class (which is acting as a Row class) doesn't know the bounds of the arrays. 

An easy fix for this is to store the number of rows (# of arrays) in the matrix class, and the number of columns (length of the arrays) in the Proxy class. Then each operator[] has the correct information to check its bounds independently of the other.

Comment: it's of course not a problem to store info about rows and columns...but the problem is, to detect, that the user is trying to set the value to check it and throw an exception where I could write out value of both row and column.....I've got no idea where in my code should I implement this :-/

Comment: Does it matter if they try to 'write' or 'read' the out-of-index memory? Both are errors. By checking within the operator[] calls you solve both problems at the same time.

Comment: This is what I meant by "check the `index` parameter in your `operator[]` overloads".  Did nobody read my answer?

Comment: @aldo I did, but maybe I didn't get what you mean with that...I'm c++ newbie, so I'm still confused with all these stuff.. :-/

Comment: Sorry aldo, when I began typing up a reply there were not yet any responses.

Comment: @optikradio I see, that you've edited your code...ty... Nevertheless - how may I access row and column values, that I store in Matrix variables from Proxy?

Comment: See the C++ FAQ section on matrix or overloading operators.

Comment: @Dworza optikradio's code for the `operator[]` overloads is pretty much what I was suggesting.  However you probably want to `throw` instead of `assert`, and since you're using `int index` instead of (the preferred) `unsigned int index` or `size_t index`, you should check for negative values as well.

Comment: @Dworza In order to access the row and column values contained in the Matrix from within the Proxy code, you would have to pass them (or at least one of them) into the Proxy constructor (Alternatively I suppose you could construct the Proxy with a reference to its parent Matrix, but that may be overly complicated).

Comment: for the others, who will have to solve the same problem - example of proper implementation of this class could be found here http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/1724/

Answer (score 1):

Your `Proxy::operator[]` overload is returning a `double&`.  This `double&` is the object that will eventually be assigned to by client code, and you can't intercept that (at least not easily).  Probably what you need to do is to check the `index` parameter in your `operator[]` overloads, and throw your own exception there rather than passing that index along to your internal arrays.